# Disable background when user "clicks" on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a website, this website has several links inside a `<li>` tag:

```
<li><a id="page7">Software</a></li>
```

When the user "clicks" on this li for example, it calls a jquery file:

```
<div id="result">
<script src="./docu2_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

This link goes to here:

```
$("#page7").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('./docu2_files/docs/software.html');
});
```

So basically when the user clicks on the diferents `<li>`, the scripts loads inside the div the content of the diferents html.

This is working, but i want to add an extra, i want to add a logo at the beginning of the website, as soon the users clicks on the `<li>`this logo should dissapear and show the content of the diferents .html

The only thing i manage to do is the viceversa, but of course that is not what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
$("#page7").click(function(){
        $("#yourLogoId").css("display", "none");
        $('#result').load('./docu2_files/docs/software.html');
})
```